# Xampp Slow Load on localhost

Tags: xampp, localhost

I am currently experiencing a problem with Xampp when my network is connected to the internet its loading really fast but once internet is not available its loading terribly slow or getting execution time out on localhost

OS: windows 7 pro 64bit
Xampp version 3.2.2

I tried changing execution time already and updated hostfile to 127.0.0.1 localhost
even tried disabling ipv6

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, After adding IP proxy settings to the browser everything seems to speed up this will also resolve gadgets connecting on local IP by adding PROXY IP that is dedicated to the server IP.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I don't know what to do. Thanks.